# how to show attributes in ontology graph using Protege?

Tags: rdf, owl, ontology, protege, protege4

I have a class Sensor Service Provider. It provides three services namely Content Service, Provider Service and Sensing Service. Furthermore the each service performs some functions like add , delete update and publish. My first question is :

1)if i model the relationship between the Provider and its services by creating an object property and linking it to the respective class is it correct?

2) How can i show these functions add, del and update and publish in my ontology. i also have a sensor class which has attributes like name, id, explain i have added them to the data type property but they aren't visible in the ontology graph.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: "they aren't visible in the ontology graph"  What ontology graph?

Comment: "if i model the relationship … is it correct"  That depends on whether it's a representation of the relationship that's logically consistent and appropriately represents the information that you want to represent.  You can model lots of things in lots of different ways.  It's usually not too hard to make something "correct"; a better question is whether it's "natural" and convenient.

Comment: hello thanks for your reply im talking about the onto graph in Protege 4.

Comment: ![Valid XHTML](http://www.w3.org/2005/Incubator/ssn/wiki/images/c/c4/Ontology-Structure-May2010.png). My Professor wants me to show the attritubes just like those in this figure accuracy frequency. With which tool can i show the attributes related to a class.